# Batch code to write System turn on time in txt file

Tags: batch-file

i need a Batch code to write System turn on time in txt file.
means i need to write the time at which my windows were turned on to a txt file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@echo off

>"C:\path\to\startup.txt" (for /f "tokens=3,4" %%a in (
  'net statistics workstation ^| find "since"'
) do (
  echo %%a %%b
))
```

Comment: Nice one! How did you figure that one out?

Comment: @Gabe I found it somewhere online when I was looking for a way to determine the uptime of a server without 3rd-party tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a scheduled task, which will run a short batch at startup (just echo date and time to the textfile and a little describing text, if you want)

```
schtasks /create /?
```

It's a bit hard to get the right syntax for the first time, but it it worth the effort.